# How can I use http request headers for content negotiation in a Mashaller?

Tags: json, scala, marshalling, unmarshalling, akka-http

My app supports protobuf and JSON serialzation. For JSON serialization I use `com.trueaccord.scalapb.json.JsonFormat`, my dtos are generated from proto definitions.

The `com.trueaccord` serializer wraps option types to JSON objects which is causing issues for some clients so I want to be able to support `org.json4s` without braking the existing clients.

I would like to be able to pick a serializer based on a custom http header called JFORMAT. The idea is that if this header is sent I will use json4s otherwise I will use the trueaccord serializer.

I managed to create a Unmarshaller which can pick a request serializer based on a header value:

```
Unmarshaller.withMaterializer[HttpRequest, T](_ => implicit mat => {
  case request: HttpRequest =>
    val entity = request.entity
    entity.dataBytes.runFold(ByteString.empty)(_ ++ _).map(data => {
      entity.contentType match {
        case `applicationJsonContentType` =>
          val jsFormat = {
            val header = request.headers.find(h => h.name() == jsonFormatHeaderName)
            if (header.isEmpty) "1.0" else header.get.value()
          }

          val charBuffer = Unmarshaller.bestUnmarshallingCharsetFor(entity)
          val jsonText = data.decodeString(charBuffer.nioCharset().name())
          val dto = if(jsFormat == "2.0") {
            write[T](value)(formats) // New Formatter
          } else {
            JsonFormat.fromJsonString[T](jsonText) // Old Formatter
          }
          dto
        case `protobufContentType` =>
          companion.parseFrom(CodedInputStream.newInstance(data.asByteBuffer)) // Proto Formatter
        case _ =>
          throw UnsupportedContentTypeException(applicationJsonContentType, protobufContentType)
      }
    })
```

I want to do the same with my Marshaller which I use with Marshaller.oneOf and the JSON handling one looks like:

```
  Marshaller.withFixedContentType(contentType) { value =>
    val jsonText = JsonSerializer.toJsonString[T](value)
    HttpEntity(contentType, jsonText)
  }
```

Is there a way to construct a Mashaller which is aware of the request http headers? The Akka HTTP docs don't have any examples and I cannot make sense of the PredefinedToRequestMarshallers.

Do I need to combine multiple marshallers somehow or can I append some metadata to a context during the request serialization I can use later in the Marshaller? I want to avoid appending meta to my dto if possible or using a custom content type like `application/vnd.api+json`

There are lots of other useful info I could use from the request when I format the response like Accept-Encoding, custom headers like unique request id to create a correlation id, I could add JSONP support by reading the `callback` query parmeter, etc.

**To clarify:** I need a solution to use the Mashaller, subclass of it or a custom version created by a factory method or maybe multiple Marshallers chained together. `Marshaller.withFixedContentType` already using the `Accept` header so there must be a way. I added added bounty to reward a solution to a specific challenge. I am ware of hacks and workarounds and I asked the question because I need a clean solution solving a specific scenario.

Comment: I may be missing something here : why don't you instantiate your marshaller after receiving the request and once you know which one you'll need ?

It makes sense on unmarshalling to manage all content type, but marshalling is pretty much you transforming your answer to whatever you want, so if you want it to depend on the request, make it a function of the request ?

Answer (score 0):

[Custom Marshallers](http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka-http/current/scala/http/common/marshalling.html#custom-marshallers) section mentions `Marshaller.oneOf` overloaded methods, that seems to be what you want:

> Helper for creating a "super-marshaller" from a number of
>   "sub-marshallers". Content-negotiation determines, which
>   "sub-marshaller" eventually gets to do the job.

The [Marshaller](https://github.com/akka/akka-http/blob/master/akka-http/src/main/scala/akka/http/javadsl/marshalling/Marshaller.scala) companion object has many methods that receive a `Seq[HttpHeader]`. You can look into their implementations as well.

I don't have the time to look into the source code myself, but if this is not enough to put you on the right path, let me know.

**Edit**:

How about?

```
get {
  optionalHeaderValueByName("JFORMAT") { format =>
    complete {
      format match {
        case Some(f) => "Complete with json4s"
        case _ => "Complete with trueaccord"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: I am using Marshaller.oneOf with multiple Marshaller.withFixedContentType marshallers but those only use the Accept header. WithOpenCharset and Opaque also doesn't have a ref to the request context.

Comment: I need a marsheller which can be used with oneOf but allows decision making based on custom headers.

Comment: @JenoLaszlo Ah, you didn't mention in your question that you're already using `oneOf` marshaller. What content type are you using? And, instead of replying on a custom header, have you considered using `Content-Type` header to to solve this?

Comment: registering a new content type for the new JSON format like application/vnd.api+json works okay but it is dirty. It is actually what I did temporarily until I figure out how to get the request headers.

Comment: it looks like the content type header is used typically in the unmarslaller and the accept header is used in the marshaller. If the accept header is not sent the first marshaller in the oneOf will be used and the content type is ignored completely. One more reason to read the request headers :)

Comment: `application/vnd.api+json` is not that bad, [GitHub](https://developer.github.com/v3/) uses something similar, among others. Using a custom header for what is the job of `Accept` sounds like a violation of HTTP contract to me. If you used it for something other than making marshaling decision, I'd agree with you.

Comment: I have two json format which are both json, have the same content type and  identical except how they handle option types, zeros, empty collections, etc. Sending a format version seems cleaner than using an alias for the json format. I could use semantic versioning but I would need access to the request in the marshaller so I can see the url.

Comment: Thanks. My question was about creating a header or request aware marshaller. Moving the content negotiation to the Routing DSL would require changing all existing routes. It is doable but it is not what I asked about.

Comment: @JenoLaszlo Ok. Coupling HTTP attributes like headers, or anything else for that matter, with Marshallers doesn't seem like a good design choice; extracting the required values keeps the separation clear.

Anyways, you've couple of options now, each with their pros and cons. 1) Use custom content type 2) Extract custom header value in route. Or you can keep looking. I'll get my coat.

Comment: Thanks man. I do appreciate your help. I did try your suggestions before. I asked the question because I genuinely curious about how can I use http request headers for content negotiation in a Mashaller and the documentation doesn't explain the topic only vaguely hinting on that it could be done.